# How to show matplotlib plot from a figure object

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my code:

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

figure = Figure(figsize=(10, 5), dpi=dpi)
```

How can I get matplotlib to show this figure ?
I can show it in tkinter, but I can't get it to show in the standard matplotlib window.

Comment: Yes I have tried `figure.show()`, but this didn't do the trick. And how do you mean use pyplot? I think I need Figure to later use `FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=self)` in tkinter.
The examples [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/index.html) all use matplotlib.figure.

Comment: What is your running environment? Operation system? Command line or any IDE?

Comment: OS: macOS Sierra.
I run it in the command line (terminal) with python 3.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I usually use matplotlib's pyplot for immediate generation (or produce images in jupyter notebooks). This would look like the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figure = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5), dpi=dpi)
plt.show()
```

This shows the (blank) figure as desired.

Comment: Using `plt.figure` instead of `Figure` does seem to work. However when I plot I also get another popup containing a matplotlib figure with a colorbar as shown [here](http://i.imgur.com/IVgZX2h.png). And when I plot inside tkinter, then decide to plot with `plt.show()` it shows the plot 2 times, as well as the colorbar plot 2 times. (When I plot 2 times inside tkinter, then without it shows 3 times, etc.)

Comment: @J.. I do not know the details of what you are doing. I can only answer what you asked in the question. If you have a different question or use-case in mind, then you should ask another question containing exactly what you're after.

Comment: Then I'll try to figure it out. And if I can't I'll create another question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

According to [AttributeError while trying to load the pickled matplotlib figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503869/attributeerror-while-trying-to-load-the-pickled-matplotlib-figure), a simple workaround is:

```
fig = plt.Figure(...)
......
managed_fig = plt.figure(...)
canvas_manager = managed_fig.canvas.manager
canvas_manager.canvas.figure = fig
fig.set_canvas(canvas_manager.canvas)
```

Note that I encountered "'Figure' object has no attribute '_original_dpi'" in my environment. Not sure if it's some compatibility issue between my PyPlot and the PyQt5. Just did a hack:

```
fig._original_dpi = 60
```

to get around this. Not sure if there are any better solutions.