# How to display plot which was saved to a variable?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

My first python question, though.

Consider me working in jupyter notebook with seaborn. Suppose I've created a plot and saved it to a variable:

```
g = sns.jointplot(ap['ap_lo'], ap['ap_hi']);
```

It will be displayed once, because I addeed `%matplotlib inline` at the beginning.

Now, after few changes, I want to display `g` again:

```
ax = g.ax_joint
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
g.ax_marg_x.set_xscale('log')
g.ax_marg_y.set_yscale('log')

sns.plt.show()
```

As you can see, I call `sns.plt.show()`, but it has no effect. I've also tried to put `g;` or `g; sns.plt.show()` at the end.

Comment: `g.show()` maybe?

Comment: AttributeError: 'JointGrid' object has no attribute 'show'

Comment: The similar question, which is NOT working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40965733/3050403

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of the question, `g` is a `JointGrid` instance.

In order to show a figure in a jupyter notebook cell, you need to state the figure. `plt.show` will not work in a new cell. The figure created by a `JointGrid` is available via the `fig` attribute. Hence the solution is to type

```
g.fig
```

Complete example image:

[image]

Comment: Looks like `.fig` is deprecated (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.html) 
it prefers `.figure`. 

Further, `.figure` has a `.show()` method (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure)  so you can run 
`g = sns.jointplot(..)`  then 
`g.figure.show()`

Answer (score -1):

In seaborn's documentation, `sns.jointplot()` returns a `JointGrid` object. And this object has some functions to display plot.

You can check documentation [here](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.html#seaborn.JointGrid).

In practice, you need to call `g.plot` or `g.plot_joint` to display your plot.

## Updated

After diving into source code, I find `joinplot` use the following functions if you use default parameters:

```
joint_kws = {}
joint_kws.update(kwargs)

marginal_kws = {}

color = color_palette()[0]
color_rgb = mpl.colors.colorConverter.to_rgb(color)
colors = [utils.set_hls_values(color_rgb, l=l)
          for l in np.linspace(1, 0, 12)]

grid = JointGrid(x, y, data, dropna=dropna,
                 size=size, ratio=ratio, space=space,
                 xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
...
joint_kws.setdefault("color", color)
grid.plot_joint(plt.scatter, **joint_kws)

marginal_kws.setdefault("kde", False)
marginal_kws.setdefault("color", color)
grid.plot_marginals(distplot, **marginal_kws)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Both `plot` and `plot_joint` require parameters. What parameters should I pass to this functions if I wan't to leave the plot unchanged? Only the scale should become logarithmic.

Comment: I also looked at the source code and red the documentation more carefully. `plot` is equivalent to creating a new plot on the JointGreed, and `plot_joint` creates the dots. I need to display an existing plot with modified axes scale, so I can't accept this answer.