# AttributeError while trying to load the pickled matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I used `pickle` to dump `matplotlib` figure as shown in [an answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12734723/1175065). Below is the code snippet-

```
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,2,3],[10,-10,30])
pickle.dump(fig, open('fig.pickle', 'wb'))
```

Below is the code snippet to load the pickled figure-

```
import pickle
figx = pickle.load(open('fig.pickle', 'rb'))
figx.show()
```

The above code shows following error-

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'manager'
Figure.show works only for figures managed by pyplot, normally created by pyplot.figure().
```

I am using Python 3.6.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit OS. Below are the more details of my environment-

```
> import matplotlib
> matplotlib.__version__
'2.1.0'
> matplotlib.get_backend()
'Qt5Agg'
> import sys
> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

*PS: My questions seem similar to [this question asked at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12734723/1175065). However, it is different since the provided answer is not running and throwing exceptions.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store and reload matplotlib.pyplot object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290370/store-and-reload-matplotlib-pyplot-object)

Comment: @DyZ: Please have a look on the updated question. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Also when I replace `figx.show()` by `plt.show()` I am able to load the figure.

Comment: @TomdeGeus: Replacing by `plt.show()` doesn't show anything. `figx.show()` shows error reported above. I don't know the exact steps to reproduce but it is showing on my machine.

Comment: How do you rund this code? Which matplotlib version and which backend are you using? What does `print(figx)` and `print(figx.canvas)` print?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: both the code snippets are stored in separate python files and executed independently. `print(figx)` returns `Figure(640x480)` and 
 `print(figx.canvas)` returns `None`

Comment: Ok, so for this to work `figx.canvas` should of course not be `None` but rather `FigureCanvasXY` with XY denoting the backend. Which backend are you using and which matplotlib version?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: It seems that `Qt5Agg` is the backend. Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need a canvas manager before you can show your figure. The same concept from question [Matplotlib: how to show a figure that has been closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729948/matplotlib-how-to-show-a-figure-that-has-been-closed/31731945#31731945) applies, you can create a function to make a dummy figure and steal its manager, as below (credit to Jean-Sébastien who wrote the answer above).

```
def show_figure(fig):

    # create a dummy figure and use its
    # manager to display "fig"  
    dummy = plt.figure()
    new_manager = dummy.canvas.manager
    new_manager.canvas.figure = fig
    fig.set_canvas(new_manager.canvas)
```

With this function you can then run:

```
show_figure(figx)
figx.show()
```

Comment: Super helpful. I found I could also replace the two lines in the second block with this one line `plt.show(show_figure(figx))` ; I had called `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` above.

Comment: Any idea on how to revise the above to load 3D plots? Current code does load them, but it is not possible to zoom in or rotate.

Answer (score -1):

The pyplot figure manager is needed to display the plot.  You can create an instance and use the imported figure by doing this:

```
plt.new_figure_manager(1).canvas.figure = figx
```

Comment: There is a better way.  The function plt._backend_mod.new_figure_manager_given_figure(1,figx) is much cleaner!